# Is it okay to Cache verified JWT token to prevent repeated verification process in spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, backend

We have a spring-boot appplication with microservice architecture.

 We have a separate service for Authentication which provides a JWT token signed with RS256 algorithm.
This token is sent in every request from client to our main application server.
I have the public key for verifying the signature.

Now this JWT token is being sent in every API request from client side as most of our URLs are protected.

Is it a good idea to cache the already verified JWT token to prevent repeated verification process of same token on every API call from same user?

Comment: But then having tokens would not make much sense anymore

Comment: I am just talking about caching the signature part of the JWT token, not the header and payload.

Answer (score 12):

There can be good reasons to cache token validation results. I would only do it if necessary, since in memory validation is fast.

Sometimes, after validating the token and identifying the user, you may want to do a fairly expensive lookup of roles etc - and you don't want to do this on every single API request

If caching then store a SHA256 hash of the token - and set a time to live no greater than the token's exp claim, as Ankur indicates.

[My post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/) explores this topic further.

API Gateway solutions often use this pattern. For example, AWS API Gateway allows you to cache a policy document that is quickly looked up when the same token is next received.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can cache the JWT token but you have to set the cache timeout which should be equivalent to token timeout.

Answer (score 1):

> The main purpose of JWT is that of not having  **server-side state**
>
> This means that the server will not store any information, nor will the session.

---

- If you cache your JWT, then your server has **State**.

  - You may have trouble later when you wanna **scale-up** your application(have multiple instances) and you may also face some **security issues**.
- If you insist on the stateful server, then it's better to use cache servers like Redis, And notice that the existent time (lifetime) of each row (each JWT) must equal to its expiry date.

> By standards, it's not a good idea to cache JWT in your server(it's
>   not a good idea to make the server stateful)

Comment: In that case, is it the same kind of state they wanted to avoid at the beginning? With multiple instances, how could it be done? Like caching on local area network with a central In-Memory DB like Redis? Or in each Instance separately, with implementation for dispatching global event to purge a token everywhere? Then JWT token would be a problem since it's not stated in server so it can't be invalidated. Of course they could set invalidated JWT in state. But the main problem remains how to invalidate a JWT in cache if User info changes.

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn’t necessarily add security issues, but you need to make sure that your cache stores verified JWT data only for as long as that token is valid. Otherwise, you are gonna have problems terminating sessions. Additionally, I’d recommend using LRU caches for this reason, so that you don’t have to store tokens that are not actively used at this point in time.

@Mehrdad HosseinNejad claimed that caching tokens adds statefullness. However, I would not say it is a critical issue in this case, since other servers that have not cached JWT in memory can still verify the JWT. The issue with scaling up is that cache may grow too large and consume too much memory on each server. Once more, I don’t believe it is much of an issue either, if LRU cache is used with proper parameters. The final suggestion in his answer is to use Redis. While it could be a good advice, it might be a slight overkill, considering the additional network latency. In-memory caching is always going to be faster, no matter what. Having said that, Redis is an extremely viable solution, if you want to avoid individual servers re-doing verification, if another server has already done that.